# get_terms sort order with child categories of varying depth

Tags: categories, search, sort, terms

I'm using `get_terms()` to search through WP categories. I'm trying to order them all by name. The code below doesn't work, apparently because there are multiple levels of child categories involved. How do I sort everything by name (whether they are parent or child categories)?

```
$searchedterms = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'name__like' => $s,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true
) );
```

Example:

Alpha (parent)

- Gamma (level 1 child)

  - Phi (level 2 child)

Beta (parent)

- Epsilon (level 1 child)

  - Kappa (level 2 child)

Zeta (parent)

should be returned as Alpha, Beta, Epsilon, Gamma, Kappa, Phi, Zeta.

Comment: I have tested the code it is working perfectly also with child categories. Can you describe more what is the $s value ?

Comment: The $s value is a search term. If you just define $s = 'smthg' and your categories are called "A smthg", "B smthg", "smthg2", etc.. then it will return those results. The parent categories seem to be ordered alphabetically, and child categories under those parent categories too, eg. (A category, AA child category, AB child category, B category, BA child category, BB child category) but I would need them to be "globally" ordered (A category, AA child category, AB child category, BA child category, etc..).

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you provide some real categories example to understand it in the better way? Sorry :(

Comment: I've edited the question with an example. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I've just tested it here too, and the correct order as you describe is returned regardless of child relationship.

Comment: The issue is with child categories with a bigger depth. I will update the question.

Comment: Adding another data point, the code posted works for me too. The terms are returned in order alpha ASC regardless of parent/child relationship & depth.  I'm using categories named `Alpha search`, `Beta search`, etc. (Appended ` search` for testing) The categories are nested as described in the original question. It might be worth checking to see if any code in your theme/plugins uses the [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms/) or [`get_terms_orderby`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_orderby/) hooks which could be altering results.

Comment: Thank you! I still didn't find the issue but at least I know it's not a standard problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the comments! With your help I managed to rule out a standard Wordpress issue. I couldn't find the culprit (As @DaveRomsey suggested, it could be one of the `get_terms` or `get_terms_orderby` hooks altering results). In any case, I solved it by sorting the array:

```
$searchedterms = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'name__like' => $s,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true
) ); 
function cmp($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
}
usort($searchedterms, "cmp");
```